# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.com.hibernate.HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my hibernate util code

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:ABC
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">abc</property>
    <property name="connection.password">***</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">3</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    </property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="org.com.tables.User_Details" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and this is the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.com.hibernate.HibernateUtil
at org.com.graphDoa.GraphDOA.salaryData(GraphDOA.java:14)
at org.com.charts.LineChart.generateSalaryPai(LineChart.java:32)
at com.kogent.action.TestAction.execute(TestAction.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:399)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:262)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:507)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

can any one help me find out what is this error all about ,am struck like nothing.If this has some thing to do with the libraries or any other thing please suggest.I am using struts 2 for mvc and hibernate 3 for database connection and tomcat 7 as a web server.

Comment: Could not initialize class **org.com.hibernate.HibernateUtil**... What's the package name of your util class ?

Comment: it is "org.com.hibernate"

Comment: I think hibernet lib is not added properly. Please check that first.

Comment: Is this what class is not found that is was posted here?

Comment: What kind of package name is "org.com.hibernate"?! In any case, if that's *your* class, it, or one of its dependencies, isn't being deployed. I'm surprised there's no "caused by" in the stack trace--are you sure there isn't?

Answer (score 4):

You can download jars related to hibernate at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3

unzip it and check whether the following files are added to your `lib` folder

```
Anttr-2.7.6.jar
asm.jar
asm-attrs.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
ehcash.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate3.jar    <--Check this version of your jar
jta.jar
log4j-1.2.3.jar
```

To run hibernate related programming and among all the jars `hibernate3.jar` is the main file..

Along with the hibernate jars you must include one more jar file related to the type of database(mysql,oracle,etc..) you use..

Try using proper versions of jar before you execute your program...some versions of jars are not supported to run...and the latest one is recommended...

Answer (score 3):

If someone is facing the same problem who are using Glassfish server you have to do the following,

1. Go your Glassfish installation path and add your database's jdbc driver under the path `glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/`
2. Restart your Glassfish server.

Answer (score 1):

use this jar:::

```
antlr-2.7.7
commons-collections-3.2.1
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final
hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
javassist-3.17.1-GA
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA
sqljdbc4-2.0(as per your database used)
```

found from:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/latest/download?source=files

Answer (score 0):

**You haven't provided the package name** in your HibernateUtil class.  If no package is defined **the class will belong to default package and you cannot get the HibernateUtil class from org.com.hibernate.HibernateUtil**