# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Hibernate.util.HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

The following is my HibernateUtil class:

```
package Hibernate.util;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
package Controllers;
import DAOImpl.ProductDAOImpl;
import Entities.Product;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping("/products.htm")
    public String getAllProducts() throws SQLException
    {
        ProductDAOImpl mapping = new ProductDAOImpl();
        Product p = new Product();
        p.setCost(1000);
        p.setName("Саморезы");
        mapping.addProduct(p);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But when I run web-app I have excpetion:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Hibernate.util.HibernateUtil
    DAOImpl.ProductDAOImpl.addProduct(ProductDAOImpl.java:24)
    Controllers.ProductController.getAllProducts(ProductController.java:20)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
```

Any Idea?
Might HibernateUtil must be registered in any place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) (did you even google?)

Comment: @Theolodis Of course, I google. But it doesnot solve the problem.

Comment: So your path is corrected? You did add Hibernate to the project path?

Comment: 1:1 copy of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.com.hibernate.HibernateUtil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951395/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-com-hibernate-hib?rq=1)

Comment: @Theolodis I have already said that it _does not work_. I check my HibernateUtil.class and Hibernate Library.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325579/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-xxx

Answer (score 4):

i think you don't have `mysql-connector.jar` in your `Classpath`

Answer (score 1):

This class first of all must be on your classpath. And then make sure that `ProductDAOImpl` ge the `sessionFactory(to eventually provide the session)` via `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()`.

You are anyway free to define this class as a bean in you application context if you like to do so.